# List is returning false, that it does not contain an item. However, when checking the list it seems to?

Tags: java, list, minecraft, bukkit

I am working on a Plugin, and came across this bug that makes no sense to me. I have a List that contains multiple strings, and when checking if it contains it use .contains it returns false in my if statement.

```
if(e.getPlayer().isOp()){

        List<String> warps = Main.getPlugin().getConfig().getStringList("warplist");
        String title = e.getLine(0);
        String toWarp = ChatColor.stripColor(e.getLine(1).toLowerCase().trim());

        if(title.equalsIgnoreCase("warp")){

            if(warps.contains(toWarp)){

                e.setLine(0, ChatColor.AQUA + "[Warp]");
                e.setLine(1, ChatColor.GREEN + toWarp.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + toWarp.substring(1).toLowerCase());

                e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Warp Sign Created!");
                e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.ITALIC + "Plugin Created By Sodex234");

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<Location> allSigns = (List<Location>) Main.getPlugin().getConfig().getList("signs");

                allSigns.add(e.getBlock().getLocation());

                Main.getPlugin().getConfig().set("signs", allSigns);
                Main.getPlugin().saveConfig();

            }else{
                e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "That Warp Does Not Exist.");
                e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You put: " + toWarp + ". Only these Warps exist: " + warps);
                e.getBlock().setType(Material.AIR);
            }

        }

    }
```

In game I get the message "That warp does not exist." - and then the List its self. However when it shows me the list, it clearly contains the item.

For instance; the list has 4 items in it, "test", "test2", "test3", "test4". I place down a sign, it knows that it is a warp, and when it comes to checking the name, it returns false? However, the name is "test" and the arraylist contains this. As you can see, I have trimmed it, striped it of chatcolors and put it in lower case (every item in the list is lower case).

Comment: Can you post the `"You put: " + toWarp + ". Only these Warps exist: " + warps` result? Exactly as seen in game

Comment: The comparison will be `case-sensitive`. Are you sure the string is present in your `ArrayList`?

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs here: http://imgur.com/bfIqYsl

Comment: Hm, that's rather weird. I'd suggest doing a for loop going over the list elements one by one, printing them and calling `.equals(toWarp)` on each one. That should give a more clear picture

Comment: There might me some character that's not being printed in the game that you don't see causing the mismatch. In the worst case you could output the string you are trying to match in the list and the lists elements as bytes and then see what's causing them to not be identical

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs I made this snipet to test that: `for(String temp : warps){
     
     if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase(toWarp)){
      
      System.out.println("match: " + toWarp + " and " + temp);
      
     }else{
      System.out.println("not a match: " + toWarp + " and " + temp);
     }
     
    }`
    and the results are: [15:25:48 INFO]: not a match: hi and hi
[15:25:48 INFO]: not a match: hi and lol
>
With some symbol?

Comment: So I guess I have to trim it down to just alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Then something goes wrong with the stripping.  As a quick fix you could strip non alpha numeric  chars from your string.  Search on Google how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stripping done to the `toWarp` string doesn't appear to be enough to remove all the characters, leaving some non-renderable characters on the string causing the mismatch.

One thing to do could be to strip all non-alphanumeric characters via some regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. It contained non-alphanumeric characters the Minecraft does not support. Used a regex to work this out:

```
toWarp = toWarp.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "");
```